# Qemu-kvm виртуалка windows 10, не работает bridge на ядре 4.20

Tags: linux, windows, сеть, kvm, qemu

UPD: проблема на ядре 4.20. На 4.19 заработало
Если (когда?) разберусь - напишу в виде ответа.

Многоуважаемый all.
Archlinux
ядро 4.20.0-3-ck (пробовал на ванильном)
qemu-patched 3.1.0 (пробовал 3.0.0)
гостевая виртуалка windows 10, обновления регулярные
сеть: bridge br0 , всегда в нем enp7s0 (основная сетевая). При включении виртуалки добавляется tap0 для виртуалки.
конфиг сети в скрипте запуска:

```
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0
-netdev bridge,br=br0,id=net0
```

когда система загружается (win10), сеть глохнет полностью.
чтобы снова заработала, нужно дернуть down/up основную сетевую enp7s0
если после этого также дернуть видимый для винды интерфейс изнутри виртуалке - сеть снова заглохнет.
Порезанный вывод inxi -F:

```
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: RUNING model: X79 v: VB1.0 serial: MB-201706282017 UEFI: American Megatrends v: 4.6.5
CPU:       Topology: 8-Core model: Intel Xeon E5-2687W v2 bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 25.0 MiB
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169
  IF: enp7s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: zz
  IF-ID-1: br0 state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: zz
```

Конфиг запуска:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -no-user-config -nodefaults -enable-kvm -m 16384 -cpu host,kvm=off,hv_time,hv_relaxed,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff,hv_vapic,hv_vendor_id=1234567890ab,hv_synic,hv_stimer -machine mem-merge=off,type=pc-q35-3.0,accel=kvm,kernel_irqchip=on,dump-guest-core=off,nvdimm=on -name winqemu -mem-path /dev/hugepages -mem-prealloc -realtime mlock=on -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=discard -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1 -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s4=1 -soundhw hda -device hda-micro -smp cores=8,threads=2,sockets=1 -vcpu vcpunum=0,affinity=7 -vcpu vcpunum=1,affinity=6 -vcpu vcpunum=2,affinity=5 -vcpu vcpunum=3,affinity=4 -vcpu vcpunum=4,affinity=3 -vcpu vcpunum=5,affinity=2 -vcpu vcpunum=6,affinity=1 -vcpu vcpunum=7,affinity=0 -boot menu=on,strict=on -bios /usr/share/ovmf/ovmf_code_x64.bin -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/usr/share/ovmf/ovmf_code_x64.bin -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/home/user/bin/ovmf_vars_x64.bin -device ich9-usb-uhci3,id=uhci -device usb-ehci,id=ehci -device nec-usb-xhci,id=xhci -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostport=1.2.1 -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostport=1.2.2 -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostport=1.2.3 -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostport=1.2.4 -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0,disable-legacy=on,disable-modern=off -object iothread,id=iothread0 -drive if=none,aio=threads,cache=unsafe,format=raw,id=drive0,index=0,detect-zeroes=on,discard=on,file=/home/user/vmdisk/winprime.raw -device virtio-blk-pci,iothread=iothread0,drive=drive0,disable-legacy=on,disable-modern=off -drive file=/home/user/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.160.iso,index=2,media=cdrom -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac=52:54:00:DF:54:01 -netdev tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,vhost=on,id=net0 -rtc base=localtime,clock=rt,driftfix=none -no-hpet -device vfio-pci,host=04:00.0,addr=09.0,multifunction=on -device vfio-pci,host=04:00.1,addr=09.1 -serial null -parallel null -vga none -sdl -daemonize -monitor unix:/tmp/qemuwin.sock,server,nowait
```

До какого-то момента работало исправно.
Сломалось меньше месяца назад, пробовал ковырять сам.
железо и конфиг не менялись.

> не было печали - апдейтов накачали.

Comment: В dmesg ничего интересного не видно? Что по счётчикам? Пакеты не отправляются? Не принимаются?

Comment: в dmesg пустовато, явных ошибок по сети нет.  
Если имеются ввиду счетчики на интерфейсе tap0 - пакеты приходят в хост-систему, но не отправляются в виртуалку.  
Собственно, такая же картина в tcpdump на остальных интерфейсах в бридже: пакеты куда-то уходят, ответа нет.  
iptables пустой, всё разрешено. ebtables не стоял, но тоже пустой.  forwarding разрешил уже после начала проблемы.

Comment: Можешь проверить то же самое поведение, но в другом дистре линукса? CentOS\Ubuntu? Чтобы проверить кто виноват - хост на арче или win10.

Comment: Другой дистр хост-системы - к сожалению не могу. Сильно "боевая" машина, проблемно поставить другую ось рядом. Сделал по-другому: попробовал чистую установку win10_1809 - сеть дохнет. win10_1803 - дохнет. Попробовал ubuntu 18.04 desktop как виртуалку (live, все те же параметры) - стало интереснее. Пока убунту пыталась dhcp - сеть на хосте жила, но трафик не шел, адрес не получался. Выставил статический адрес - сеть сдохла.  Получается проблема всё-таки где-то в Арче. И раз гугл не помогает - где-то накрутил лишних настроек, или апдейт криво прошел.

Comment: Очень интересно. Откатился на ядро 4.19 - всё заработало. Буду искать что изменилось и как исправить. Если (когда?) найду - напишу как ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в sysctl параметре `net.core.default_qdisc` - настроил значение `fq`.
В версии 4.20 такой вариант параметра перестал существовать, но это почему-то повлияло только на виртуалку.
По дефолту сейчас выставляется значение `fq_codel`, и с ним никаких проблем, всё работает.

```
sudo sysctl -a | grep qdisc
net.core.default_qdisc = fq_codel
```

Стоит отметить, что с неправильным параметром воспроизводится отвал только сети виртуалки.
Отвал сети на хосте воспроизвести не удалось.